# Laravel shop cart

Tags: php, laravel

I use [darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart](https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart).

In my app I have cart and wishlist. And want to save all it in database for each user. So I do all step by step like in [instruction](https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart).

to register wishlist I use ServiceProvider (like in instruction)

```
$this->app->singleton('wishlist', function($app)
        {
            $storage = new DBStorage(); <-- Your new custom storage
            $events = $app['events'];
            $instanceName = 'cart_2';
            $session_key = '88uuiioo99888';
            return new Cart(
                $storage,
                $events,
                $instanceName,
                $session_key,
                config('shopping_cart')
            );
        });
```

But how can I save it for each individual user? What is `$session_key = '88uuiioo99888';`? If I use it, in my db all withlists saved like one row with ID 88 (88uuiioo99888 trimmed to 88). In servce provider I can't use `Auth::user()->id` to set user ID as `$session_key`.

My problem is next - all wishlists of many users are saved like one global wishlist with ID (key) 88.

So how can I save wishlists for each user separatly?